# How would I translate this part of ::jsonb::text POSTGRESQL to loopback?

Tags: sql, postgresql, loopbackjs

How would I translate something like, following, to work with Loopback?

```
SELECT * FROM bbb where b_names::jsonb::text ilike '%test%';
```

Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you meant how to do the pattern matching in loopback .. so here it is:

`bbb.find({where: {b_names: {like: '%test%'}}}, function(err, cb) { ... });`

You can find more info here: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Where+filter